# How to diff/merge changes in stages, with automation

Tags: regex, merge, diff

The objective is to transfer a set of changes from a fairly large body of C++ source code (500+ files) to a newer version of the same code base, in stages. Each stage will be committed and tested in isolation. The stages relate to portability and have little or no functional effect, so only regression testing is required.

The changes of interest can be easily identified by a simple regex eg insertion of 'const', insertion of #ifdef blocks. There are maybe 20 stages, and maybe a few thousand changes all up. Most files are affected, and there are bound to be some merge conflicts to review. I can live with that.

The code bases have no specific common ancestor. The repo is SVN, but quite different trees. I am told that the operation is somewhat similar to a git partial commit or incremental commit, but I have no git skills or any desire to acquire them unless there is no alternative.

Otherwise, I've looked at a lot of different diff/merge tools and drawn a total blank. A folder/diff/merge tool with a regex to filter changes might work.

Any suggestions or ideas very much appreciated.

Comment: Unless you have a common ancestor (for a 3-way merge) you only have the option of a 2-way merge (comparing/diffing the two code bases file by file and doing the merging/editing more or less by hand).

Comment: So the question becomes: are there any tools to make that a bit less manual? I haven't found any so far. Business opportunity???

Comment: If they are the same code base, how can there be no common ancestor? Perhaps some files do have common ancestor, at least?

Comment: At some point the code was checked out and modified, and checked into a different repository as a new tree. The modifications have no version history, and the two trees are (now) in different repositories. A common ancestor could be created, but it doesn't exist now.